# Returning unique values from a COUNTIF function (Excel)

Tags: excel, unique, countif

[image]

Formula in F2 is:

=COUNTIFS(C:C,E2,B:B,"<>Closed/Lost")

I would like it to return number of **unique** values from Column A, so desired output is 3

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: It's Microsoft 365

Comment: Can you then show some sample data and desired output? You can use `UNIQUE()` function.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the question with sample data and desired output

Comment: Give a try to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we include the criteria for the "Status" column ("<>Closed/Lost")?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245972/discussion-between-dave-and-harun24hr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,C2:C6=E2)))
```

In case of possibility of no match with criterial then use-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,C2:C6=E2,""))<>""))
```

To include `Status` column use-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,(C2:C6=E2)*(B2:B6<>"Closed/Lost"),""))<>""))
```

[image]